# Wordpress Dequeue Localized Script not working

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to remove plugin's javascript and replace it with my own.

The plugin is registering the scripts with this code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learndash_30_template_assets' );
function learndash_30_template_assets() {
    // If this function is being called then we are the active theme.
    $theme_template_url = LearnDash_Theme_Register::get_active_theme_base_url();

    /**
     * @TODO : These assets really should be moved to the /templates directory since they are part of the theme.
     */
    wp_register_style( 'learndash-front', $theme_template_url . '/assets/css/learndash' . leardash_min_asset() . '.css', array(), LEARNDASH_SCRIPT_VERSION_TOKEN );
    wp_register_script( 'learndash-front', $theme_template_url . '/assets/js/learndash.js', array( 'jquery' ), LEARNDASH_SCRIPT_VERSION_TOKEN, true );

    wp_register_style( 'learndash-quiz-front', $theme_template_url . '/assets/css/learndash.quiz.front' . leardash_min_asset() . '.css', array(), LEARNDASH_SCRIPT_VERSION_TOKEN );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'learndash-front' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'learndash-front', 'rtl', 'replace' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'learndash-front' );

    wp_localize_script( 'learndash-front', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
    wp_localize_script(
        'learndash-front',
        'ldVars',
        array(
            'postID'      => get_the_ID(),
            'videoReqMsg' => esc_html__( 'You must watch the video before accessing this content', 'learndash' ),
        )
    );

    if ( get_post_type() == 'sfwd-quiz' ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'learndash-quiz-front' );
        wp_style_add_data( 'learndash-quiz-front', 'rtl', 'replace' );
    }

    $dequeue_styles = array(
        'learndash_pager_css',
        'learndash_template_style_css',
    );

    foreach ( $dequeue_styles as $style ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( $style );
    }

}
```

I want to replace the 'learndash-front' script. I tried normal wp_dequeue_script and wp_enqueue_script:

```
function replace_script()
{
    wp_deregister_script( 'learndash-front' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'learndash-front' );

    wp_register_script( 'cu-learndash-front', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/learndash/ld30/assets/js/learndash.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cu-learndash-front' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'replace_script', 100 );
```

This adds my custom script, but the default plugin script is still loaded however moved to the end of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept looking and actually found a working solution in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/262301/cannot-deregister-a-script-using-wp-deregister-script).

I had to dequeue the script with add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_262301_wp_footer', 11 );

Comment: hi Jan,  many thanks for sharing your findings with us.  I am very glad that you could solve this issue.  Have a great day! regards Zero